# Camel route - get JMSMessageId after sent

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, spring-jms

How can I get JMSMessageID in camel route producer (with Spring context),
JMSMessageID needs to be generated by MQ server, like it works with native JMS.

In the [camel's documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)
JMSMessageID is in section "consumer",
"Camel adds the following JMS properties to the In message headers when it receives a JMS message",
but I need it from producer side after send.

I can's use tmpReply queue with camel's InOut.

I suppose, I need to use [MessagePostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/core/MessagePostProcessor.html), or [MessageSentCallback](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-jms/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jms/class-use/MessageSentCallback.html), but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The JMSMessageID is automatic set by Camel after the message has been sent by the JMS client, so you have it as the messageId on the Camel Message instance

Comment: It supposed to be, but in.header, in.body and out is null.
May be I have wrong settings?
Camel version is 2.18.1

Comment: What JMS client/broker do you use? It may be that it does not provide the message id when sending.

Comment: I use: springframework 4.3, spring-context, camel-core, camel-spring

Comment: I suppose, it's org.apache.camel.component.jms

Comment: JMS client, eg ActiveMQ, WebSphere, or some other broker, its really that JMS client that controls what JMS message ID gets assigned and when its available for you

Comment: IBM MQ - It tested and works with native JMS, so I suppose that the problem is somewhere in camel or spring...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
from("someRoute")
    .to("jms://OUTPUT.QUEUE?includeSentJMSMessageID")
    .log("JMSMessageID = ${header.JMSMessageID}");
```